# 19.10 Users tab doesn't show any user

Tags: users, 19.10

The users exist when I check `/etc/passwd`, but are not shown here:

[image]

Comment: Something relevant in journal? `journalctl | grep -i gdm`

Comment: @nobody Getting a never ending output in the console with this. Is there something more specific with regard to gdm I could look for?

Comment: No, saddly not, I was fishing.